How to compute the expected cost of crafting in a video game
I've been trying to calculate the expected cost of crafting items in a video game.
The crafting process:
We have an unlimited number of tier $0$ (lowest tier) items available, using one comes with a gold cost.
It takes 2 items of the same tier to combine them to the next tier with $65$% chance for success and $35$% chance for failure with a $50$% chance for one of the items to lose a tier when failing (item destroyed when failing at the lowest tier).
Every attempt to combine items also costs gold, the higher the tier the higher the cost.
My approach so far:
I've approached this problem by computing the expected value for each tier, but I don't know how to confirm the correctness of my approach and I don't know if this approach accounts for the fact that you could fail multiple times.
let $C_t = $ cost for one crafting attempt at tier $t$
$P_S = P(Success) = 0.65$
$P_{FK} = P(Fail) \cdot 0.5 = 0.175$  [Fail but keep tiers]
$P_{FL} = P(Fail) \cdot 0.5 = 0.175$  [Fail but one item loses a tier]
$E_C(t) = $ Expected cost of crafting item tier $t$
$I_C = $ cost of one tier $0$ item
$$
E_C(1) = 2 I_C + P_S \cdot C_1 + P_{FK} \cdot 2 C_1 + P_{FL} \cdot (2 C_1 + I_C)
$$
$$
E_C(t) = 2E_C(t-1) + P_S \cdot C_t + P_{FK} \cdot 2 C_t + P_{FL} \cdot (2 C_t + E_C(t-1))
$$
So my question is, does $E_C$ correctly determine the expected cost for crafting an item tier $t$ given the described crafting process and if not, what's wrong and how does the correct $E_C$ look like?
Edit: Clarification on the crafting process.

Let $V_t$ be the "value" of a tier t item. Set up an equation: "value of inventory before one crafting attempt" = "value ... after". Since you'll never have leftover items, the expected cost is the "value".

If  I understand your comment correctly, you are suggesting to just record the cost of crafting an tier $t$ item. However, I am looking for the expected cost for any tier $t$ item, accounting for the probabilities for success, failure while keeping tiers and failure while one item loses a tier.

Value before = $2V_t + C_{t+1}$.
Value after = $P_S * V_{t+1} + P_{FK} * (2V_t) + P_{FL} * (V_t + V_{t-1})$.

(then just solve for $V_{t+1}$)

Oh I see. Could you maybe hint me in the right direction to understand why this works, or maybe even write an answer explaining it? Because after trying this, all I can say is that the results could make sense, but I'd like to know that it is actually correct and understand why.

What is a Tier 5 ($V_5$) item worth in gold? To do that we'll end up solving for $V_1$...$V_5$. When you craft something your inventory changes, but the total expected value of your inventory stays the same. So, make an equation setting the value of the crafting inputs equal to the expected value of the crafting outputs.
I can add an answer later tonight if that's helpful.

I don't really get what you are calculating. I will first demonstrate a simpler game to illustrate how a model would look like.
Rolling the dice
Set up
So the game is role a dice and you win, if you role a $6$ and you lose otherwise. One role costs $5$ gold.
Question
What is the expected price for a win.
Model
A win can take arbitrarily long, as you can role $1$ to $5$ for the first $n-1$ times and finally $6$ at the $n$-th time. Hence, one possible model consists of the outcome of countable many rolls. One role is modeled by the set
$$
\hat{\Omega} = \lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6\rbrace
$$
the $\sigma$-alegbra is the power set of $\Omega$ and the probability measure $\hat{P}$ is given by a uniform distribution, i.e.,
$$
\hat{P}(\lbrace k\rbrace) = 1/6 \quad\text{for} \quad k \in \Omega.
$$
Now the entire process is modeled by infinitely many rolls, i.e.,
$$
\Omega = \hat{\Omega}^{\mathbb{N}}.
$$
Hence an element $(\omega_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $\Omega$ is the sequence of the results of infinite many rolls. The $\sigma$-algebra is the product $\sigma$-algebra and the probability measure $P$ is the product probability measure.
The random variable that tells you how often you have to roll the dice until you win is given by
$$
Y\colon
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{rcl}
\Omega&\to& \mathbb{R}\\
(\omega_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} &\mapsto& \min \lbrace n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \omega_n = 6\rbrace
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Now the random variable $X$ that tells you the price is just $X = 5Y$. Note that in your example this needs a bit more attention. In order to calculate the expected price you have to calculate the expected value of $X$. Hence, we need to calculate the induces measure by $X$ (or $Y$). It is probably a bit more illustrative to show this for $Y$.
\begin{align*}
P\big(Y^{-1}(\lbrace 1\rbrace)\big) &= P(\lbrace (w_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mid w_{1} = 6\rbrace) = 1/6 \\
P\big(Y^{-1}(\lbrace 2\rbrace)\big) &= P(\lbrace (w_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mid w_{1} \neq 6, w_{2} = 6\rbrace) = 5/6 \cdot 1/6 \\
&\mspace{6mu}\vdots \\
P\big(Y^{-1}(\lbrace n\rbrace)\big) &= P(\lbrace (w_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mid w_{j} \neq 6 \ j < n, w_{n} = 6\rbrace) = (5/6)^{n-1} \cdot 1/6
\end{align*}
Now we have
$$
\mathbb{E}(X) = 5 \mathbb{E}(Y) = 5\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n P\big(Y^{-1}(\lbrace n\rbrace)\big)
= 5\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (5/6)^{n-1} 1/6
= 5/6 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (5/6)^{n-1}
$$
There are several methods how you calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (5/6)^{n-1}$, e.g., by observing that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n-1} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}$$
This gives then
$$
\mathbb{E}(X) = 5/6 * 36 = 30.
$$
Your problem
In order to get calculate the expected price for your experiment you need to model it by sequences of single outcomes. Then you can define the random variable more or less the same as in the previous example and then you have to calculate the induced measure.

Could you show me how to do this for my problem? Otherwise I'm still in the same position where I try to put a solution together without knowing if it is correct. Also I don't quite see how you went from the definition of $E(X)=5E(Y)$ to the final line.

@darthDoe In your example there are missing assumptions. The expected value is linear (it is an integral). Hence, $X = 5 Y$ implies $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(5Y) = 5\mathbb{E}(Y)$.

What missing assumptions? And I meant how you arrived at $E(X)=5/6 * 36 = 30$

@darthDoe You have to evaluate the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (5/6)^{n-1}$. The answer is $36$. I gave instructions how to evaluate this (use $x=5/6$ in following displayed equation), but you can also just ask wolframalpha.

Ah I see. Well, can you show me how to apply this to my problem? If there is any information missing I'm happy to provide it, if you let me know.

@darthDoe how many items do I have? Can I run out of items? Is my goal to reach tier $t+1$ or even higher? If I can run out of items then the expected price is not a meaningful object, since there is a positive probability that you never reach your goal. Then you need to specify how you punish this scenario in your model.
Moreover, I think the random variable for such an experiment will be already quite unhandy.

We have unlimited items, but each item costs gold. I want to calculate the cost for any tier $t$ item. It takes 2 tier $0$ items to create a tier $1$ item, and 2 tier $1$ to create a tier $2$ item and so on. The maximum tier is $10$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
